# Encrypt database password in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, password, oracle-linux

I have a small script to compile an Oracle Form, in this script i login to the database and I would like to have the password in this script encrypted.

```
for i in `ls *.fmb`
do
echo Compiling Form $i ....
/u01/oracle/middleware/domains/test/config/fmwconfig/components/FORMS/instances/test/bin/frmcmp_batch.sh userid=test/username@password batch=yes module=$i logon=yes module_type=form compile_all=yes window_state=m$
done
```

Is it possible to have the password replaced by a reference which is stored in a password protected/encrypted file like this? `userid=test/username@P4ssw0rd` where "P4ssw0rd" would be stored in said file.

How would i make that reference?

Are there better options or reasons why NOT to do this?

Many, many thanks in advance!

Roël

Comment: ``for i in `ls *.fmb` `` replace this with `for i in *.fmb`. And double-quote your variables each time you use them (`$i` → `"$i"` at the very least, etc.)